# ¿Cómo mostrar decimales grandes en python?

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente funcion

```
import math
def decimales(n):
    result=float((3+math.sqrt(5))**n)
    return result
print decimales(22)
```

al mandarle el valor 22 me regresa 6.57833635663e+15
 quiero que me de como resultado el valor real

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, para mi  ```6.57833635663e+15``` es un real hecho y derecho; solo que está escrito en notación cientifica (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_cient%C3%ADfica) . Que es un real para ti @Alexander A.R?

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada, un concepto importante: **una cosa es el dato y otra muy distinta, la representación del mismo**. Lo que estás viendo es como Python representa por defecto un número del tipo `float`. Para demostrar esto, podemos hacer:

```
print decimales(22)
print '{:.17g}'.format(decimales(22))
6.57833635663e+15
6578336356630531
```

Como puedes observar, en el primer caso, el formato por defecto reduce el número a una expresión exponencial, esto por que la  representación básica de un `float` en `python v2.x` es `{:.12g}`, que en este caso se comporta, mostrando un número de hasta 12  dígitos (incluidos decimales significativos) tal como es, y si tiene más dígitos, con notación exponencial. Modificando el formato de la representación a `{:.17g}`, dicho sea de paso, el que usa `Python 3x`, puedes ver una representación completa del número.

**Nota**: Puede ser útil consultar las opciones de [formateo de cadenas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) en `Python 2x`.